# "Invalid Toolchain." iTunes Connect is rejecting iOS 10 App Beta built with Xcode 8 Beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

According to the release notes, builds of iOS 10 Beta apps should work on TestFlight: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/

However, when I submit them, I get this error:
**ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta OS X builds.**

... This app is "distributed for beta testing" and I want to submit a new build. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because I'm using Xcode8 Beta 5, not Xcode8 Beta 6.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that I was able to submit using the latest Xcode beta. Leaving this question here for anyone who encounters the same issue.